# Internal Storage on HTC Desire

Tags: file, data-storage, android

I'm trying to save a file to internal storage (not SD Card). As the documentation points out, if I use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, the data will be placed under `/Android/data/<package_name>/`, but there's nothing there. This code is taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html). Similar code worked on Archos, though.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
txtList.append(file.getPath());

try {
    path.mkdirs();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(data);
    os.write(data);
    is.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
}
```

I use Android SDK 2.1. Permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`is already added in the manifest. No error in logcat. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update.
The problem disappears when I simply unplug the device and run the app. A friend told me he got the same problem and solved it by closing any apps that are likely to access the SD card, e.g. Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Internal and External storages. You are talking about internal storage, while actually you are using **external** storage:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

The resulting file will be located here: `/mnt/sdcard/DemoPicture.jpg`. But if your really want to use internal storage, take a look at [`Context.openFileOutput`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) function.

---

**EDIT:**

File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
    txtList.append(file.getPath());

```
try {
    path.mkdirs();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(data);
    os.write(data);
    is.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to write a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I mean, external storage. Yes, the path is shown as `/mnt/sdcard/DemoPicture.jpg`, but I couldn't see anything there. Do I miss something?

Comment: Hmm, works on my phones. How do you check that file was created? Do you use some file explorer application? Or maybe `adb shell`?

Comment: I use file explorer. I checked the storage state and it says `shared` --> the media is present not mounted, and shared via USB mass storage. I don't understand what "mounted" means. I thought when I connect the device to PC then it IS mounted.

Comment: You should "unshare" the USB storage. When you have shared your SD Card via USB, your external storage is in read-only mode for Android. See my edit to the answer, I've added usage of `Toast` instead of `Log`. This should give an idea what's going wrong (you should see Toast message if you have shared your USB device.

Comment: Ok, I've looked around and there seems to be nothing else to add to the code. How can I "unshare" the storage?

Comment: Your code is fine. Just unplug the usb cable and launch your application Applications screen. This should do the trick.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've unplugged and even uninstalled several times. I also tried with HTC Wildfire. Strangely it works when I use the emulator. What do you think could be the issue?

Comment: If you are using some kind of file explorer, make sure you hit "refresh" button in it. Normally such explorer re-scan directories not too often.

Comment: As another way to check your file existence: connect your device via usb and then run command `adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard`.

Comment: It says "opendir failed, Permission denied". When I check the storage state, it keeps saying cannot read/write.

Comment: This is crazy!! I have to set up rw permission, but I can't get root access. Keep going.. *sigh* btw, +1 for your assistance :)